# Hibernate named query ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception, named-query

This might be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433345/hibernate-gives-a-strange-classcast-exception-using-transformers) but did not get proper solution over there.
I am using named query to fetch some details as below and returning as list of **string**,

```
<sql-query name="getContactIds">
    <return-scalar column="id" type="string" />
        <![CDATA[Select c.id as id from CRM.dbo.contact c where is_deleted=0]]>
</sql-query>
```

But when calling this query, I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map**

```
SearchTemplate searchTemplate = new SearchTemplate();
searchTemplate.setNamedQuery("getContactIds");
searchTemplate.setNamedQueryResultType(String.class);
salesforceContactIds=contactDao.getSfContactIds(searchTemplate);
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: I think table name is `contact`. So can you try removing `CRM.dbo.` from the query and try. i.e., `Select c.id as id from contact c where c.is_deleted=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPQL is query language from Hibernate/JPA. And it works with entities and not with tables. So if you have **Contact** java entity with field **deleted** which is mapped to Contact table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT", schema = "name")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
    private boolean deleted;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
```

then select should be something like

```
select * from Contact c where c.deleted = 0
```

And then get id or other necessary fields from **Contact**.

If you want to use SQL syntax then you need to use NamedNativeQuery

Comment: Yes your right.. it works only with entities. I mapped the result to Contact pojo and the problem is solved.. Thank you